# How to create Amazon MWS developer account , so that it can be used for multiple seller accounts, to fetch orders , products and update inventory

Tags: amazon-mws, amazonsellercentral

I am working to create Amazon MWS developer account , my requirement is to access the seller panel of different clients. I have already gone through the videos and links for the creation of MWS developer account, where its asking for the paid service. Is this the only way and the correct one , which would fulfill my requirement.

Any link where I can get clear information is required

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about whether or not you need a Seller Central account in order to register as an MWS developer, then the answer is yes, you do. Unfortunately there's no way around this that I am aware of.

On another important note related to your question, Amazon is no longer granting new MWS credentials or upgrading existing MWS access roles due to them wanting to migrate developers towards using their `Seller Partner API (SP-API)` (this was taken directly from an email from Amazon's developer registration team). **If you are working EXCULSIVELY with sellers that already have MWS credentials, then this doesn't apply to you** as the traditional way to get an MWS Auth Token from other sellers still works last I checked, but if not then you'll need to start researching SP-API and not MWS.

More information on the SP-API registration, setup and service authentication across multiple vendors, can be found [here](https://github.com/amzn/selling-partner-api-docs/blob/main/guides/developer-guide/SellingPartnerApiDeveloperGuide.md).